# If infinitely many points of a sequence are given, is it possible to find out the recurrence relation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

I was thinking about sequences and stumbled upon a concept. If infinitely many points of a sequence are given, is it possible to find out the recurrence relation?

Please enlighten.

Comment: What do you mean 'the' recurrence relation?

Comment: Depends on whether you make any assumption about how the sequence is generated. In general, knowing $a_{2n}$ for all $n$ doesn't tell you anything about the $a_{2n+1}$. About the only thing that you can say is that if the $a_{2n}$ don't converge, then neither will the full sequence $a_{n}$. But you don't even get the converse - it's entirely possible for the $a_{2n}$ to converge, yet for $a_{n}$ to diverge...

Comment: Do you mean that you give all points or only a subsequence? And do you assume that the sequence is defined by some reccurence relation of some given form?

Comment: @GitGud recurrence relation of the elements of a sequence.

Comment: @JérémyBlanc all points are given. and yes.

Comment: @Hawk I don't understand. A sequence can be obtained a closed form of two different recurrence relations, so the word 'the' confuses me.

Comment: @Hawk In this case, it seems plausible. For example if you know that the reccurence relation is polynomial, it will work with even finitely many (depending on the degree). If you now that it is given by some form involving finitely parameters, it also seems feasible. But in general it is not clear.

Comment: @JérémyBlanc how should i clarify myself?

Comment: @GitGud I am not very advanced, so if you will please elaborate the doubt, maybe I could clarify the question.

Comment: Actually I am specifically saying that, a recurrence relation that is satisfied for all the points.

Comment: @Hawk I just say that the question is probably too broad. In general if you just know that there is a recurrence and dont fix the form, I guess that you cannot know which one it is by looking at the points. Except by constructing one strange function that sends $a_n$ onto $a_{n+1}$ for each $n$ and extending it in any way to $\mathbb{R}$. Did you have some special kind of recurrence in mind?

Comment: @JérémyBlanc I have nothing on my mind and am just wondering.

Comment: Ok, so as I said if you take any sequence such that the following hold: if $a_k=a_l$ then $a_{k+1}=a_{l+1}$, then you can find a recurrence given by a function $f$: just choose a function such that $f(a_i)=a_{i+1}$ for each $i$. This looks stupid (and is probably), but shows that you need to restrict your type of recurrence to say something interesting.

Comment: How about the prime numbers ?.

Answer (score 1):

If a sequence has a recurrence (say $a_{n + k} = f(n, a_n, \ldots, a_{n + k - 1})$, you can construct an infinitude of recurrences for it, e.g. by constructing one for $a_{n + k + 1}$ like $a_{n + k + 1} = f(n + 1, a_{n + 1}, \ldots, a_{n + k - 1}, f(n, a_n, \ldots, a_{n + k - 1}))$ and so on.

For each sequence $a_n$ you have the (trivial) recurrence $a_n = f(n)$.

Comment: Why is the number of recurrences countable? It depends on $f$, which is a function and thus is not countable.

Comment: @JérémyBlanc, you are right. I was thinking of recurrences given as explicit expressions.

Answer (score 0):

The recurrences
\begin{align*}
a_0 &= 1 \\
a_{n+1} &= a_n
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
b_0 &= 1 \\
b_{n+1} &= b_n^2
\end{align*}
generate the same sequence of values.  Are they the same recurrence?

Comment: Agreed, but if you are given infinitely many values, does this argument hold?

Comment: All values are given in this example.